# Could not chdir to home directory

Tags: login, home-directory, ldap, autofs

I have configured my machine with autofs to mount an LDAP users directory when they log in to a machine. I have created a directory in home called /guests. However when the LDAP user logs in, it isn't mounted to this drive, would anyone know where I go to make the new home dir for the LDAP users logging in? I also have a local user that I want to remain untouched.

Comment: Please show us the actual paths involved. Is this `/guests` or is it `/home/guests`? And please give us some more context. What Ubuntu is this? How did you set up LDAP? Why isn't the drive mounted when the user logs in, how do you mount it? Please [edit] your question and add some detail.

Answer (score 0):

## Try this..

```
sudo chown -R $USER /home/guests

chmod u+x -R /home/guests
```

you may find full information here

https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/autofs#Configuration